# Correct translation of こともない in this sentence

Tags: grammar, translation

Just before the quoted passage, the narrator says a whistling going "Don!" happens at the same time as he stumbles and ends up stooped. Then:

> もちろん、いくら昔の話でも発車のベルは「ドン！」などとは鳴らないし、発車のベルが人を突き飛ばすこともない。

My attempted translation:

> Of course, though this happened a long time ago, it couldn't be possible that the bell would go “Don!” and send someone flying.

Here I assume こともない means "it's not possible/the case that..." Is this correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「～こともない」 is made of 「～ことはない」(don't ever~~) + 「も」(either).
「～ことはない」 is the negation of 「～ことがある」(occasionally do~~).

Compare:
ベルが人を突き飛ばす**ことがある**。-- The bell occasionally/sometimes pushes people away.
ベルが人を突き飛ばす**ことはない**。-- The bell wouldn't ever push people away.
ベルが人を突き飛ばす**こともない**。-- The bell wouldn't ever push people away, either. / Nor would it ever push people away.

> 「ドン！」などとは鳴ら**ないし**、発車のベルが人を突き飛ばすこと**もない**。

「～～ないし、～～もない」 means "neither ~~ nor ~~".

"The bell would never go 'bump!', nor would it ever push people away."

Comment: This answer goes directly to the question I asked, so I moved the tick here. When I first read the sentence, a similar translation occurred to me, but I rejected it because I couldn't figure out why the narrator would reject that a bell goes 'Don'. I guess that sound must have rung out in his boyish imagination but on reflection he must have realised it didn't happen. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> こともない means "it's not possible/the case that.

こともない is a kind of emphasis of "have/do not either."

It is emphasizing or pointing out that a bell would never go "don" or shove someone.

Answer (score 2):

> -「ドン！」
>   - 人を突き飛ばす  "*to shove people by the explosion of the round shot*"

「ドン!」in the story of がばいばあちゃん, I think, is not a mere onomatopoeia of something, but the sound of a blank shot by a heavy gun or a cannon. In Meiji era they fired a blank shot to tell citizens the time of noon, which is written [here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8D%88%E7%A0%B2). Sometimes ドン meant, I once heard,  not only the sound of a cannon but a cannon itself in those day.

There is another ドン which is something to do with this ドン; that is used in 「位置{いち}に着{つ}いて、よーい（用意{ようい}）、ドン」 which means *On your mark!, Ready! / Get set!, Go!*. The last ドン is of course the sound of firing a starting pistol.