# やることもなく ; "doing nothing" or "doing nothing but/except"

Tags: translation

Attempting to make some flashcards from the dialogue in *Dad of Light* on Netflix.

Near the very beginning of Ep1, we have the following:

**夏休みにやることもなく**フローリングの床に寝そべって足の力でクルクル回るという

English subtitles read:

*I had nothing else better to do during summer vacation than lie on the kitchen floor and turn in circles using my legs.*

my question is about やることもなく -- I can think of two ways this could be:

"During summer vacation I did nothing.  I was lying on the floor, turning in circles using my legs."

--or--

"During summer vaction I did nothing *except* lie on the floor, turning in circles using my legs."

Can anyone point me toward a resource to understand this usage?  I found something close from user [Chocolate](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/9831/chocolate) [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47800/correct-translation-of-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-in-this-sentence/47870#47870).

Comment: 「夏休みにやることもなくフローリングの床に寝そべって足の力でクルクル回るという」 is not a complete sentence. Can you provide the full sentence? 続きがありますよね？

Comment: P.S. I found it. The full sentence is 「あのころの僕はといえば　夏休みにやることもなく　フローリングの床に寝そべって　足の力でクルクル回るという　謎の遊びに夢中だった。」, right?
 https://www.fmsubs.com/subtitles/Fainaru-fantaji-XIV-Hikari-no-otousan/123105-jpn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 夏休みにやることもなく...

means "During summer vacation I *had nothing to do*, and/so..."

「やること」 → "things to do" "something to do"
「やることがない」 → "have nothing do to" (≂ 「ヒマだ」 in your context)

cf:
「話すこと」 → "things to talk about"
「話すことがない」 → "have nothing to talk about"
「書くこと」 → "things to write about"
「書くことがない」 → "have nothing to write about"
「見るもの」 → "things to see"
「見るものがない」 → "there's nothing to see"

The continuative form (連用形) な**く** is used here to connect two clauses, like a conjunction "and" or "so".

---

<sub>As for the も replacing the が, it's used to indicate...</sub>

> <sub>も　〘副助*〙
>
>   ⓬ さりげなくとりたてて、文意をやわらげる。
>
>   「お腹**も**すいたし、食事にするか」「天気**も**いいから、散歩でもしよう」
>
>    -- from 明鏡国語辞典 (*明鏡 categorizes 係助詞/binding particle as 副助詞/adverbial particle)</sub>

Comment: when you say なく is the continuative form (that's usually て form, right?) what verb is it the continuative form of?

Comment: @Floydius The なく is the continuative form of the i-adjective ない. Both なく and なくて can be used to connect clauses. (なく sounds less casual.) For more on this: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14409/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2934/9831

Answer (score 0):

> (1) 夏休みにやることもない。そして、フローリングの床に寝そべって
>   (2) 夏休みにやることも**なく**フローリングの床に寝そべって
>   "During summer vacation I did nothing. I was lying on the floor, turning in circles using my legs."

"point me toward a resource"は出来ませんが、質問者が考えた１番目の案は、(2) ではなく、(1) に対するものです。
(2) は (1) と違って、「やることも**なく**」と連用形で終わっていますので、例えば「やることもなく **～する**」のように用言が続く必要があります。

(2) の例では、「～する」に相当する部分は「（床に）寝そべる」です。

従って、(2) の解釈は質問者が提示した２番目の案だけです。

> "During summer vaction I did nothing except lie on the floor, turning in circles using my legs."

因みに、質問者が提示した下記の例は、(1) と同じく終止形「ない」で終わっています。

> (3) ベルが人を突き飛ばすこともない。-- The bell wouldn't ever push people away, either. / Nor would it ever push people away.

Comment: Once my Japanese is good enough to read all of this fully, I'm certain it will make sense to me!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think なく is close to "without".
So やることもなく is "without even  something I want to do."

I interpret the く as a word expressing a state or a circumstance of someone/something.

for example

> 彼は朝食を食べることなく家を出て行った

If translating it into English, it would be like

> "He left home without having breakfast."

And く is a conjunction. it make us feel a connection to the following clause.
Your two sentences are very good, but you shouldn't punctuate after く.
 If I translate that sentence into English, it would be like this:

> During summer vacation, without even  something I want to do I was lying on the floor, turning in circles using my legs.

So I mean, く expresses a state in pallarel rather than a cause and result in order.

I'm so sorry for my bad English.